# Upslope area shows an error stating tool needs graphical user interface

Tags: qgis, saga, gui, catchment-area

[image]

I tried delineating catchment area of a place. First I downloaded the DEM TIFF from internet. Then reprojected it to the required CRS. Then I used the Fill Sink tool and Strahler Order after that. Then I created a shapefile and located a single point in the river where I wanted to find the catchment. Then, I used Find XY tool to get coordinates and used the coordinates in the Upslope Area tool. I put the DEM without sinks layer in elevation, deterministic 8 in method and 1.1 in convergence. Then I run it but I always got the error.

Comment: Please remember include the exact software release and put the full error message in the body of the Question, as text, not only as an image, since images are not legible on all devices and can't be searched by others with the same message.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the log message gives you more information, menu view > panel > log message. Other recommendations

- If the basin raster is not generated, check if the DEM coordinate system matches the point coordinate system (CRS). This tool does not have reprojection.
- It may be a processing error, create a new profile, in configuration > user profile > new profile.
- If this fails try running directly in SAGA,

Answer (score 1):

A small addition needs to be made in the `ta_hydrology_upslope_area.txt` file included in the SAGA installation files.
In the txt file, the `Upslope Area` part should be edited as `Upslope Area |4` and saved.

[image]

[image]

source: https://youtu.be/t-2ExoyhIfA

Comment: please, what is the solution for mac? it has dylib files only